# Inconveniente para mostrar en tabla, registro seleccionado con el componente combobox

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, deseo pedirles el favor con el siguiente requerimiento que tiene que ver para imprimir los datos en una tabla, dependiendo del valor seleccionado de un combobox, vale mencionar que estoy utilizando los siguientes componentes:
Un archivo con nombre conexión.php que esta dentro de una carpeta con nombre connect, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
 <?php 
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="clasicotk";
    $port=3308;
    
     $con=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db,$port);
     //mysql_select_db($db);
    if ($con->connect_errno){
    echo "Error al conectar Base de datos: ". $con->connect_errno;
    
    } else {
      echo "Conexión exitosa";
    }
    
    ?>
```

Tengo el siguiente archivo Artista.php:

```
 <?php
      require_once("connect/conexion.php");
      $sql="Select Distinct Artista From discos ORDER BY Artista ASC";
      $res1=$con->prepare($sql);
      $res1->execute();
      $result = $res1->get_result();
      $rows = $result->num_rows;
    ?>
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
      <center> 
         <head>
          <title>Listado Discos </title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Artista.js"></script>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          
          <style type="text/css">
          table{
              border:1px solid;
              border-collapse:collapse;
              padding: 10px;
              }
             th, td, tr{
                border: 1px solid; 
             }
          
          </style> 
    
         </head>   
            <body>
             Seleccione Artista:
             <select id="Artista" onchange="seleccioneArtista()"> 
               
              <?php 
                  while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>",$rows['Artista'],$rows['Artista']); /*Ojo código incluido*/
                  }
                ?>
             </select>
             <br></br>
             <table>
                 <thead> 
                    <th style="width: 30%">Iddisco</th>
                   <th style="width: 10%">Artista</th>
                   <th style="width: 10%">Trabajo</th>
                   <th style="width: 10%">Género</th>
                   <th style="width: 10%">Año</th>
                   <th style="width: 30%">Enlace</th>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody id="ans"> 
                 </tbody>
             </table>
            </body> 
       </center>     
    </html>
```

Dentro de la carpeta js, tengo un archivo con nombre Artista.js, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
function seleccioneArtista(){
    var x = document.getElementById("Artista").value;
       
    $.ajax({
    url:"showArtista1.php", 
      method: "POST",
       data:{
           id : x
       },
       success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $("#ans").html(data);
    
       }
    })
    }
```

El código del archivo showArtista1.php es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
    $k=trim($_POST['id']) ?? null;
    if ($k) {  
        echo $k;
        require_once("connect/conexion.php");
    $consulta1="SELECT Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Genero, Anho, Enlace FROM discos WHERE Artista=$k"; 
       echo $consulta1;  /* Al imprimir la consulta me muestra lo siguiente:  SELECT Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Genero, Anho, Enlace FROM discos WHERE Artista=Artista seleccionado  */

        if($stmt1=$con->prepare($consulta1)){
            $stmt1->bind_param("s", $k); 
            $stmt1->execute();
            $stmtn1->bind_result($Iddisco,$Artista,$Trabajo,$Genero,$Anho,$Enlace);   
            while ($stmtn1->fetch()) { 
                print("<tr>");
                printf("<td>%s</td>",$Iddisco);
                printf("<td>%s</td>",$Artista);
                printf("<td>%s</td>",$Trabajo);
                printf("<td>%s</td>",$Genero);
                printf("<td>%s</td>",$Anho);
                printf("<td>%s</td>",$Enlace);
                print("</tr>");  
              }   
        } else {
            # Falló la preparación, manejar error o lo que quieras
            echo "If ha fracasado, ERROR";
           } 
        } else {
            echo "Post vacío"; 
            }
     ?>
```

Al ejecutar el código me muestra el siguiente error:
If ha fracasado, ERROR

Viendo el código del archivo   showArtista1.php, el error en el que está apareciendo el error es el siguiente:

```
if($stmt1=$con->prepare($consulta1)){
```

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Atentamente

Hernán Camilo Martínez

Answer (score 1):

Obtienes ese mensaje porque la consulta generó error al ejecutarse:

```
$consulta1="SELECT Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Genero, Anho, Enlace FROM discos WHERE Artista=$k"; 
echo $consulta1;
/* Al imprimir la consulta me muestra lo siguiente:
    SELECT Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Genero, Anho, Enlace
    FROM discos
    WHERE Artista=Artista seleccionado
*/
```

Copia esa consulta y ejecútala en PhpMyAdmin, verás que el error está relacionado con `seleccionado` y es porque el valor debe estar encerrado entre comillas:

```
$consulta1 = "SELECT Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Genero, Anho, Enlace
    FROM discos
    WHERE Artista = '$k'";
```

### Solución:

Al estar usando consultas preparadas, en lugar del valor debes colocar un marcador `?` que será remplazado al enlazar el parámetro:

```
$consulta1 = "SELECT Iddisco, Artista, Trabajo, Genero, Anho, Enlace
    FROM discos
    WHERE Artista = ?";
```

Ese marcador será remplazado con el valor correcto (incluyendo comillas) cuando ejecutes:

```
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $k);
```

Referencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php